# Раскрутка сайта - рекламные ссылки в подвале

Tags: seo

Добрый день!

Мне предложили в подвале разместить ссылку на некий сайт одежды. Просто ссылку, не баннер. Сайт одежды вроде адекватный, а не вредоносный сайт.

Слышал мнение, что это и есть black раскрутка и что в этом случае мой сайт поисковые краулеры понизят в рейтинге из-за того, что......тема моего сайта не совпадает с одеждой.

Кто что может рассказать с точки зрения раскрутки - безопасно ли так делать? Ссылка будет ВИДИМОЙ, т.е. синей на белом фоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так никогда не делал, точно не скажу. Вот что советует Яндекс по этому поводу:

http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/recommendations/links.xml

http://webmaster.ya.ru/replies.xml?item_no=325

Если кратко — не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Можете написать как ответ? я приму его, все четко.

Answer (score 0):

[[@severemax](/users/24776/severemax)](/users/24776/severemax) *Бытует такое мнение: если вы разместите на своем сайте чужую ссылку, то трафик вашего сайта будет поделен с данной ссылкой*, и, естественно, рейтинг может упасть. Ну и, конечно, учитывайте репутацию сайта, **если на сайте партнере есть спамный контент, то не только этот сайт попадает под санкции, но и ваш сайт тоже**! Учитывайте этот момент. 
Так, например, порносайты не могу разместить свои ссылки на сайтах с детской одеждой. 
Но а если вы не хотите, чтобы ссылка индексировалась, или вы не хотите делить трафик с вашим партнером, то используйте **noindex или nofollow**  в зависимости от вашего предпочтения и оптимизации вашего сайта.